Rails: How to render a string containing both user input and added HTML entities (composed in a model method)?
While the below model method technically works, it is not safe, because name and profession is user input:
def name_with_html_entities
  "#{name} &bull; #{profession}".html_safe
end

So how would I need to change that for it to be safe?
EDIT: I know that this could be "solved" in the View layer, by rendering <%= sanitize(@model.name_with_html_entities) %>, but the idea is to secure such potential security holes "at their root" (in the model method), so no accidents can happen.

At some point you need to sanitize- you can do it at input or output — but if you want to utilize html_safe, um, safely, you need to sanitize.

I tend to sanitize at input so nothing unsafe is persisted.

You could add validations to your model fields so that for example only letters are accepted.

I think you should weigh the potential security benefits (which are very questionable) against the code quality implications of giving your models yet one more responsibility. Making your model into even more of a god class for the sake of security sounds like a fools errand.

If you want to move this logic out of the view into somewhere where it's more easily testable consider a helper or the decorator pattern.

It may not be the "purest" of solutions (in terms of theoretical code organization), but in some cases it can be preferable to be very pragmatic about a special case:
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord

  include ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper
  
  def name_with_html_entities
    sanitize("#{name} &bull; #{profession}".html_safe)
  end

end

